# Procedure to find direction of triangle

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry

I'm trying to write a procedure or function to find the direction in which a 2D triangle points. The triangle is assumed to be isosceles. While I can see the basic outline of what I want to do, making this into a procedure/function is proving harder. This is very basic Mathematica programming, I think... :(

Suppose that points *p*, *q*, and *r* are three arbitrary 2D points assumed to form an isosceles triangle:

[image: a triangle]

```
triangles = 
{
  {{30.07, 11.04}, {20.07, 35.905}, {40.905, 19.095}}, 
  {{82.918, 26.9417}, {77.5077, 43.5925}, {88.3281, 43.5925}}}

aTriangle =  First[triangles];  
{p, q, r} = aTriangle

(* 
{{30.07, 11.04}, {20.07, 35.905}, {40.905, 19.095}}
*)
```

The side lengths are found easily enough:

```
{EuclideanDistance[p, q],
 EuclideanDistance[p, r],
 EuclideanDistance[q, r]}

(* 
{26.8005, 13.5011, 26.7708}
*)
```

and clearly in this case `pr` is the different side that helps define the direction:

```
midPoint = {(p[[1]] + r[[1]])/2 , (p[[2]] + r[[2]])/2}

(* 
{35.4875, 15.0675}
*)
```

Then all that's left is to find the angle of the line `Line[{midPoint, q}]`, which is probably something like this:

```
ArcTan[q[[1]] - midPoint[[1]], q[[2]] - midPoint[[2]]] / Degree

(* 
126.497
*)
```

But I want this to be automated, and I can't see how to do this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Given that the triangle might not exactly be isosceles, let's characterize this direction as being *from the triangle's center towards the most distant vertex*:

```
ClearAll[direction];
direction[t_List] := 
 With[{center = Mean[t]}, 
  t[[First[Ordering[N[Norm /@ (# - center & /@ t)], -1]]]] - center]
```

(**Edit** As @R.M. notes, `N` needs to be applied for `Ordering` to work consistently and correctly.)

One advantage of this approach is that it works for any polygon.  Another is that it does not require any additional specification such as a tolerance for testing approximate equality of sides.

As an example,

```
t = {{30.07, 11.04}, {20.07, 35.905}, {40.905, 19.095}};
center = Mean[t];
Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[Black], Polygon[t], Red, Arrow[{center, center + direction[t]}]}]
```

[image: Figure]

Note that the direction is given as a vector (which carries the additional information about the distance from the triangle's center towards this extreme vertex).  For other forms of output, this is readily converted into a unit vector (by normalizing it) or an angle.

---

#### Edit

Notice that for squat, flat isosceles triangles (where the apex angle exceeds 60 degrees), this solution determines that the "pointing direction" is from the center towards one of the *base* vertices, not towards the apex.  If that is not the intention, then additional analysis is needed.  One way is to determine that among all the possible directions from the center, the one most different from the other two is the one to pick:

```
direction[t_List] := Block[{center = Mean[t], s, l, a},
  s = # - center & /@ t;
  l = Norm /@ s;
  a = Abs[RotateLeft[l, 1] - RotateLeft[l, 2]];
  s[[First[Ordering[N[a], 1]]]]
  ]
```

In this implementation (which is written for clarity rather than brevity), `s` lists the three possible directions, `l` lists their lengths, and for each entry in `l`, `a` lists the differences in lengths *between the other two*.  The last line returns the direction where that difference is the smallest (as a vector from the center to the vertex, exactly as before).

Comment: The "center towards most distant vertex" approach won't work for flatish isoceles triangles... for example a triangle with 1°, 1° and 178° as angles.

Comment: @R.M Or even 62°-59°-59°.  (To see this set up a `Manipulate` using `t = {{e, e}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}` and vary `e` between -1 and 1, say.)

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the answer - neat idea. Luckily the edge cases aren't an issue for my application. :)

Comment: @R.M. You are correct--thank you--but not for the reason you might think!  The problem is that `Ordering` is *different* for exact values than it is for numerical values.  (Although this is well documented behavior, it's a subtle and nasty one IMHO.)  One solution is to convert the norms to machine numbers.

Comment: @whuber I wasn't referring to Ordering's behaviour... rather that the most distant vertex (or vertices) in such cases would be the two vertices whose subtended angles are equal, rather than the third vertex which is what the OP wants.

Comment: @Brett (and R.M.) I think there may be a difference of opinion over which way an isosceles triangle "points".  In my solution, I take its "sharpest" vertex--the one furthest from the center--to be a pointing direction.  I think you are taking its apex to be the pointing direction, even for squat, flat isosceles triangles.  That's a reasonable interpretation, but requires a different approach.  In fact, in some marginal cases it will be difficult to ascertain which vertex really is the "apex."

Comment: @whuber Fair enough. I agree that the OP hadn't given a definition of what they meant by "direction", but I interpret it this way, because then there is no ambiguity as to which direction it points in — there is only one vertex that is the answer. Using the sharpest vertex doesn't quite help, because then there are two equally sharp vertices and which one `Ordering` picks depends on the order in which it was input. For example, try running a manipulate as Brett suggested, with `direction[RandomSample[t,3]]` inside your `Graphics` construct

Comment: $R.M. There are two "equally sharp" vertices only when you are using exact numbers.  With machine numbers, in most cases there are three distinct edge lengths and three distinct vertices.  One can resolve that issue with some analysis of the triangle to see whether two edges (or angles) are much closer to each other than they are to the third.  It's not hard to do but rather fussy.  If your application doesn't need such analysis--e.g., you are using narrow triangles to indicate directions or limited fields of view--that's a plus :-).

Comment: @whuber thanks - particularly for the clarity!

Answer (score 5):

If the triangle is isosceles, the corresponding median line is orthogonal to the side. Therefore I think the following should be the most robust solution (note that it also works for triangles where the arrow tip angle is larger than 60 degrees, however it assumes the triangle is not degenerate; also for equilateral triangles it will return just one of the three possible directions):

```
direction[t:{{_,_},{_,_},{_,_}}] := ArcTan@@
  (Sort[Table[Module[{tipcand  = t[[i]],
                      basecand = t[[Range[3]~Complement~{i}]]},
    ({Abs[#1.#2]/Sqrt[(#1.#1)(#2.#2)],#1}&)[tipcand-Plus@@basecand/2,
                                            Subtract@@basecand]],
              {i, 3}]][[1,2]])/Degree
```

Answer (score 4):

I am taking here the simplest approach and simply putting the reasoning you followed above into a single module:

```
dir[t_, prec_] := Module[{d1, d2, d3},
  d3 = EuclideanDistance[t[[1]], t[[2]]];
  d2 = EuclideanDistance[t[[1]], t[[3]]];
  d1 = EuclideanDistance[t[[2]], t[[3]]];
  v = If[Abs[d1 - d2] < prec*(d1 + d2), Normalize[t[[3]] - (t[[1]] + t[[2]])/2],
       If[Abs[d1 - d3] < prec*(d1 + d3), Normalize[t[[2]] - (t[[1]] + t[[3]])/2],
        If[Abs[d3 - d2] < prec*(d3 + d2),  Normalize[t[[1]] - (t[[3]] + t[[2]])/2],
         Null]]];
  ArcTan[v[[1]], v[[2]]]
]
```

The function takes a triangle as first argument, and compares its length with some precision (for your input data, 0.1% is a good choice of precision, so `0.001`). Then calculates the direction as a vector (`v`) and return its argument with `ArcTan`'s two-argument variant.

```
In[21]:= Map[dir[#, 0.001]/Degree &, triangles]
Out[21]= {126.497, -89.9997}
```

Comment: Thanks - and your descriptive explanation is appreciated, too!